# Replacing entire node using web.config transforms resulting in error

Tags: xml, xpath, msbuild, msbuild-4.0, xml-document-transform

I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have a node in a web config:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    ...
    <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
           <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
           </dependentAssembly>
           ....
```

and I want to **replace** this with:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

using MsBuild `TransformXml`. I can't quite figure out the correct syntax for the xdt attributes though. The following (which looks correct to me) :

```
<dependentAssembly xdt:Transform="Replace" 
                                    xdt:Locator="Condition(param/@name='Newtonsoft.Json'">
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Is resulting in an error:

> XmlNodeException : Transform and Locator attributes must contain only
>   a type name, or a type name followed by a list of attributes in
>   parentheses.

what am I missing here?

I can't alter the original BTW, this must be done using transforms.

Comment: Can you try this for your transform - `<dependentAssembly xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Condition(./_defaultNamespace:assemblyIdentity/@name='Newtonsoft.Json')">`

Comment: That results in the error `XmlNodeException : '/configuration/runtime/_defaultNamespace:assemblyBinding/_defaultNamespace:dependentAssembly[./_defaultNamespace:assemblyIdentity/‌​@name='Newtonsoft.Js‌​on']' has an invalid token.` @alex. Thanks

Comment: hmm, the only place i can find the error you're originally getting is - https://github.com/micahlmartin/XmlTransformer/blob/master/src/XmlTransformer/XmlElementContext.cs#L292 - which is a 3rd party parser...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute `name='Newtonsoft.Json'` is located in a parent element named `assemblyIdentity`, so I'm not sure why `param/@name`. The correct XPath expression to test if child element named -ignoring namespaces- 'assemblyIdentity' has attribute `name` value equals 'Newtonsoft.Json' would be as follow :

```
xdt:Locator="Condition(*[local-name()='assemblyIdentity']/@name='Newtonsoft.Json')"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem basically the name space.
Define this namespace in your xdt file.

```
<configuration xmlns:asm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
```

Use the new namespace like this:

```
<asm:assemblyBinding>
  <asm:dependentAssembly xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Condition(asm:assemblyIdentity/@name='Newtonsoft.Json')" >
    <asm:assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <asm:bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </asm:dependentAssembly>
</asm:assemblyBinding>
```

I think this is a bit more elegant than local-name() version.